# Change xml attributes with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

Here is the content of my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data-sources>
    <data-source id="mariaDB-162b8e6bd5d-176d08c17fde61cb" provider="mysql" driver="mariaDB" name="MariaDB - app" save-password="true" show-system-objects="true" read-only="false">
        <connection host="172.23.0.4" port="3306" server="" database="portal" url="jdbc:mysql://172.23.0.4:3306/portal" user="portal" password="fakepassword" home="/usr" type="dev">
            <network-handler type="TUNNEL" id="ssh_tunnel" enabled="false" save-password="false">
                <property name="sshConnectTimeout" value="10000"/>
                <property name="port" value="22"/>
                <property name="implementation" value="jsch"/>
                <property name="authType" value="PASSWORD"/>
            </network-handler>
            <network-handler type="PROXY" id="socks_proxy" enabled="false" save-password="false">
                <property name="socks-port" value="1080"/>
            </network-handler>
            <network-handler type="CONFIG" id="mysql_ssl" enabled="false" save-password="false">
                <property name="ssl.public.key.retrieve" value="false"/>
                <property name="ssl.verify.server" value="true"/>
                <property name="ssl.require" value="false"/>
            </network-handler>
        </connection>
    </data-source>
    <filters/>
</data-sources>
```

For example I want to be able to change

```
<connection host="172.23.0.4" port="3306" server="" database="portal" url="jdbc:mysql://172.23.0.4:3306/portal" user="portal" password="fakepassword" home="/usr" type="dev">
```

to

```
<connection host="172.28.0.8" port="3306" server="" database="portal" url="jdbc:mysql://172.28.0.8:3306/portal" user="portal" password="fakepassword" home="/usr" type="dev">
```

So i need to change the host property and the url dynamically.
I tried:

`xmlstarlet ed -u "/data-sources/data-source/connection[@host]/@host" -v '172.28.0.8' .dbeaver-data-sources.xml`

but it doesn't work, the file doesn't change.

Comment: What version of xmlstarlet? If you're using version 1.0.2 or higher, you can use the `-L` (or `--inplace`) command line argument to edit the file in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the `--inplace` advice, changing multiple attributes must be done with multiple invocations

```
declare -A host=([old]=172.23.0.4 [new]=172.23.0.8) 
new_url="jdbc:mysql://${host[new]}:3306/portal"

xmlstarlet ed -u "//connection[@host = '${host[old]}']/@host" -v "${host[new]}" file.xml |
xmlstarlet ed -u "//connection[@host = '${host[new]}']/@url"  -v "$new_url"
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data-sources>
  <data-source id="mariaDB-162b8e6bd5d-176d08c17fde61cb" provider="mysql" driver="mariaDB" name="MariaDB - app" save-password="true" show-system-objects="true" read-only="false">
    <connection host="172.23.0.8" port="3306" server="" database="portal" url="jdbc:mysql://172.28.0.8:3306/portal" user="portal" password="fakepassword" home="/usr" type="dev">
      <network-handler type="TUNNEL" id="ssh_tunnel" enabled="false" save-password="false">
        <property name="sshConnectTimeout" value="10000"/>
        <property name="port" value="22"/>
        <property name="implementation" value="jsch"/>
        <property name="authType" value="PASSWORD"/>
      </network-handler>
      <network-handler type="PROXY" id="socks_proxy" enabled="false" save-password="false">
        <property name="socks-port" value="1080"/>
      </network-handler>
      <network-handler type="CONFIG" id="mysql_ssl" enabled="false" save-password="false">
        <property name="ssl.public.key.retrieve" value="false"/>
        <property name="ssl.verify.server" value="true"/>
        <property name="ssl.require" value="false"/>
      </network-handler>
    </connection>
  </data-source>
  <filters/>
</data-sources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!